# Reference for closed form integral of $\int_0^1 dz\,z^n/(z-a)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, mathematica

Is there a closed form (non-recursive) expression for the definite integral

$$\int_0^1 dz \frac{z^n}{z-a}, \qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \text{ and } a\notin (0,1)$$

for general $n$ and $a$ given in terms of logarithms?  *Mathematica* is able to give them for any given integer $n$ (I made a table for $n=\{0,\ldots, 5\}$), but I can't find in the literature how the incomplete Beta function is related to logarithms:

[image]

Anyone pointing me to the appropriate formulae in the [NIST Handbook of Mathematical functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov) or in [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/) would be fantastic.

Comment: Depends. What do you consider as a closed form?

Comment: That's a good question, and something that I should have mentioned.  The answer appears to be a sum of polynomial in $1/a$ and logarithm.  So I guess I am looking for something of the form:  $\sum_n c_n(1/a)^n + \text{logs}$.  where the $c_n$'s are explicitly given (in terms of factorials, or Harmonic numbers, etc..)

Comment: If you want it in terms of factorials then the Beta function can be written in terms of the Gamma function which can be written in terms of factorials thus a "closed" form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** You may write 
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1  \frac{z^n}{z-a}dz&=\int_0^1 \frac{z^n-a^n}{z-a}dz+a^n\int_0^1 \frac{1}{z-a}dz\\ 
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}z^kdz+a^n\int_0^1 \frac{1}{z-a}dz\\ 
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}\int_0^1 z^kdz+a^n\left. \log (z-a)\right|_0^1\\ 
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a^{n-k}}{k}+a^n \log \left(1-\frac1a\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\dd z\,{z^{n} \over z - a}\,,\qquad n\in{\mathbb Z}_{+}\
     \mbox{and}\ a \not\in \pars{0,1}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> Lets $\ds{{\cal I}_{n} \equiv \int_{0}^{1}{z^{n} \over z - a}\,\dd z}$ such that

\begin{align}
{\cal I}_{n}&=\int_{0}^{1}{z^{n - 1}\pars{z - a} + a z^{n- 1} \over z - a}\,\dd z
={1 \over n} + a{\cal I}_{n - 1}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> {\cal I}_{n}&={1 \over n} + {a \over n - 1} + a^{2}\,{\cal I}_{n - 2}
> ={1 \over n} + {a \over n - 1} + {a^{2} \over n - 2} + a^{3}\,{\cal I}_{n - 3}
> \\[5mm]&=\cdots=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over n - k} + a^{n}\,{\cal I}_{0}
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad
> {\cal I}_{0}=\int_{0}^{1}{\dd z \over z - a}=\ln\pars{\verts{1 - {1 \over a}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{z^{n} \over z - a}\,\dd z}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over n - k} + a^{n}\,\ln\pars{\verts{1 - {1 \over a}}}}}\,,\qquad
n\in{\mathbb Z}_{+}\ \mbox{and}\ a \not\in \pars{0,1}
$$